# Replace divs with content from JSON call

Tags: jquery, json, html

I am receiving content from a JSON call and I would like to populate 3 object that returned with response in `news_item` class as follows:

```
<div class="news"> 
        <div class="news_item" style="margin-left: 0 !important;">

        <div class="ni_image">
            <a href="/HaberDetay/TITLE/ID"><img src="IMAGE"width="203" height="109"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ni_text">
            <div class="ni_text_title">TITLE</div>
            <div class="ni_text_content"> 
                CONTENT
            </div>
        </div>
        </div> 
</div>
```

I am able to receive the data as follows. but not quite sure how to populate the `news_item` div as above. I also need to clear, `news`  and replace everything with data from JSON response.

```
var newsByCity = JSON.parse(msg);

                $.each(newsByCity, function (key, item) {
                    alert("Code: " + item.City + " ,Name: " + item.Title + " ,Country: " + item.County);

                });
```

any pointers? how can i do this?

EDIT: i m getting back TITLE, ID, CONTENT etc. I just need to see how i can create this new divs.

Comment: yeah. how do i do it? thanks.

Comment: I have problems matching City, Title and Country to TITLE, ID, CONTENT from your description and to the div classes "ni_text", "ni_image", "ni_text_title" and "ni_text_content". Which part of your JSON will end up in which DIV and how exactly does your JSON look like?

Comment: @devnull69 assume TITLE, ID, etc is in the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind you jQuery templating is still in beta (can be DL here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl)

Create a jQuery template of this HTML, with the Title/ID/Content etc where they will be appearing `${TITLE}`/etc. Basically like this:

```
<div class="news_item" style="margin-left: 0 !important;">
    <div class="ni_image">
        <a href="/HaberDetay/${TITLE}/${ID}"><img src="IMAGE"width="203" height="109"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ni_text">
        <div class="ni_text_title">${TITLE}</div>
        <div class="ni_text_content"> 
            ${CONTENT}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then just create the template and append it to news.

`$('#yourTemplateScriptArea').tmpl(newsByCity).appendTo('.news');`

Here's an intro on Templating if you've never done it before.
http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates.aspx

Comment: jQuery templating is looking good but worth noting it is still in beta and not ready for production usage.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention that! You can also look into `knockout.js`. It handles templating very similarly, and is incredible in its own right.

Comment: i dont think i need knockout. i am aware of it. it doesnt really fit into my purpose. thanks though

Answer (score 1):

To create new elements you can create them with JS or jQuery. jQuery is easier but has a higher overhead.

```
// Element to append to
var target = $('.news');

// Create the new element in a jQuery object
// and use the appendTo method to attach it
// to the DOM element
$('<div />').html('<p>New div created</p>')
            .appendTo(target);
```

Alternatively you can find existing dom elements and replace the text or HTML

```
var target = $('.news');

// Replacing text
target.find('.ni_text_title').text('New news title');

// Replacing HTML
target.find('.ni_text').html('<div class="ni_news_text">...</div>');
```

You can empty the textual or HTML contents of an element by passing an empty string to the `.html` and `.text` methods. If you leave them blank the method will return the current text or HTML of that element.

Hope that helps.