# Jquery tmpl and razor mix

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
<script id="newsTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    <div class="news_item" style="margin-left:0 !important;">
        <div class="ni_image"><img src="@Url.Action("ViewImage", "Image", new {path = "${Thumbnail.Path}"})" alt="${Title}" /></div>

    </div>


</script>
```

I am trying to render the image on page, and I have to pass the Thumbnail Path to image controller for that.

Jquery tmpl doesnt like it.

How can i fix this?

For background please see: 
[Replace divs with content from JSON call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848471/replace-divs-with-content-from-json-call)

Comment: code wasnt showing. now u should see it. thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough info here to really answer the question ... what is getting rendered before applying the template?  what data are you applying in the `.tmpl` call?  And what should the URL look like to successfully load the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by mixing server code (Razor) and client code.

You are using Razor (on the server) to create a link, but in order to create the link you need the `path` value which is in the `${Thumbnail.Path}` field (client-side) that Razor does not have access to.

I would need to know a bit more about your code in order to help you come up with a solution.

Comment: Please see this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848471/replace-divs-with-content-from-json-call